# Apache Poi how to add header at start in every printed page?

Tags: java, excel, header, apache-poi

I have a dynamic project witch is printed on some pages (number of pages depends on content from web (different amount)).

I have covered most of the code (have one header at the start of the sheet)

but I don't know how to multiple this header at the start of every new printed page page.

My header look's like this:

[image]

Comment: Does https://www.roseindia.net/jsp/poi/repeatingRowsAndColums.shtml or http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/printing-issue-Landscape-fixed-width-repeating-rows-td2301101.html help?

Comment: In current `apache poi` versions this is simply [Sheet.setRepeatingRows-](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setRepeatingRows-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress-).

Answer (score 3):

From your description [Repeat specific rows or columns on every printed page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/repeat-specific-rows-or-columns-on-every-printed-page-0d6dac43-7ee7-4f34-8b08-ffcc8b022409) could be what you wants. In current `apache poi` versions this is simply [Sheet.setRepeatingRows-](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setRepeatingRows-org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress-) for repeating rows.

Following code shows a complete example which creates the kind of `Excel` sheet, your screen shot seems to show.  It uses up to date methods from current `apache poi 4.1.0`. Since `apache poi` is highly in development, code samples are outdated very fast.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.PropertyTemplate;

class CreateExcelRowsToRepeatAtTop {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   PropertyTemplate propertyTemplate = new PropertyTemplate(); // needed for drawing borders

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

   // the header rows and cells
   String[][] headers = new String[][] {
    new String[] {"XRace", "Track Race", "Track 1", "Track 2", "Track 3", "Track 4"},
    new String[] {"", "", "Best lap 1:23", "Best lap 2:02", "Best lap 3:30", "Best lap 6:22"},
   };

   int[] columnWidths = new int[] {15*256, 30*256, 15*256, 15*256, 15*256, 15*256};

   for (int r = 0; r < headers.length; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
    for (int c = 0; c < headers[0].length; c++) {
     Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
     cell.setCellValue(headers[r][c]);
    }
   }

   for (int c = 0; c < headers[0].length; c++) {
    sheet.setColumnWidth(c, columnWidths[c]);
   }

   // add merged regions as needed
   sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 1, 0, 0));
   sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(0, 1, 1, 1));

   // set alignments
   for (int c = 0; c < headers[0].length; c++) {
    CellUtil.setAlignment(CellUtil.getCell(CellUtil.getRow(0, sheet), c), HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    CellUtil.setVerticalAlignment(CellUtil.getCell(CellUtil.getRow(0, sheet), c), VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
    CellUtil.setAlignment(CellUtil.getCell(CellUtil.getRow(1, sheet), c), HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
    CellUtil.setVerticalAlignment(CellUtil.getCell(CellUtil.getRow(1, sheet), c), VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
   }

   // set higher row 2
   CellUtil.getRow(1, sheet).setHeight((short)1000);

   // draw borders
   propertyTemplate.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(0, 1, 0, headers[0].length-1), BorderStyle.MEDIUM, BorderExtent.ALL); 

   sheet.createFreezePane(2,2); // freeze pane on screen

   sheet.setRepeatingRows(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("1:2")); // set repeating rows for printing

   // set print setup; fit all columns to one page width
   sheet.setAutobreaks(true);
   sheet.setFitToPage(true);
   PrintSetup printSetup = sheet.getPrintSetup();
   printSetup.setFitHeight((short)0);
   printSetup.setFitWidth((short)1);

   // set table data rows
   Object[][] data = new Object[1000][6];
   for (int r = 0 ; r < data.length; r++) {
    data[r] = new Object[] {r+1d, "Race " + (r+1), 12d*(r+1), 23d*(r+1), 34d*(r+1), 45d*(r+1)};
   }

   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r+2);
    for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
     Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (data[r][c] instanceof Double) {
      cell.setCellValue((Double)data[r][c]);
     } else if (data[r][c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String)data[r][c]);
     }
    }
   }

   // draw borders
   propertyTemplate.drawBorders(new CellRangeAddress(2, 2+data.length-1, 0, data[0].length-1), BorderStyle.THIN, BorderExtent.ALL); 

   // apply drawed borders to sheet
   propertyTemplate.applyBorders(sheet);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution (works in my project, probably not the best)

`sheet.createFreezePane(row from, row to);`